# Hibernate GWT: Turn off hibernate logging to console

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I've searched a lot of topics in the internet with similar problems, but any can help me to solve this problem. So I'm using GWT + Hibernate (jars):

```
junit-4.11-beta-1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

and all I want to do is disable console output like for example:

```
2012-12-14 23:41:09 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
2012-12-14 23:41:09 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

cause it makes my app very slow. How can i do that?

Comment: First, that doesn't make your app very slow. Second, do you want to hide SQL output or what?

Comment: First - it does cause output contains about 100 lines or more?

Comment: Second - no SQL output, I will show you in my first post, I want to disable output like that:                                  2012-12-16 10:14:32 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2012-12-16 10:14:32 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
2012-12-16 10:14:32 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2012-12-16 10:14:32 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The question has no relation to GWT. The impact of performance by these logs is Zero.**

If you need to turn off your hibernate logs then you need to first find how you hibernate is being initialized and then address the log level for hibernate either there or in you applications log setup. [Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) .

```
1) In code via some Annotation
2) from a hibernate properties file
3) from hibernate.cfg.xml
4) from log4j.properties
```

We **use hibernate.cfg.xml** and turn off hibernate sql logs using
`<property name="show_sql">false</property>`

You need to find somethign similar for your application.

Comment: But how to do it? I'm using default settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j configuration set hibernate logger to higher level:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="error"/> 
</logger>
```

If you don't want to see info level hibernate messages.

Comment: But I don't have any configuration file, Do I have to create it in war/WEB-INF/classess/ ?